# gmp extension is not loaded but is required for sending push notifications with payload or for VAPID authentication. You can fix this in your php.ini

Tags: php, push-notification, xampp, laravel-5.8

I am referring Below Link:

> https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/push-notifications-with-laravel-and-webpush-446884265aaa

This link for push notification in **laravel5.8**

I am getting below error-

```
ErrorException (E_USER_WARNING)
[WebPush] GMP extension is not loaded but is required for sending push notifications with payload or for VAPID authentication. You can fix this in your `php.ini`.
```

I tried below solution-

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gmp
```

also enabled extension in php.ini file `extension=php_gmp.dll`

Comment: Remember to restart your apache "sudo service apache2 restart"

Answer (score 2):

in php.ini make sure to unable :

> extension=gmp

Then Restart your apache

> sudo service apache2 restart

More info:
php.ini path "/etc/php/**7.X**/apache2/"

***Check your php version (using php -v)*** and replace the **X** value